# Duplicate records in query result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's the query that works:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID
     ,T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode
     ,T_ActionTicketLog.UserID
     ,T_TicketStatus.Name
     ,T_OrderTicket.OrderID
FROM T_ActionTicketLog 
INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus 
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket 
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 21780101
```

There are 27 records returned, which is ok.

But, I want to add one more field to result set in this way:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID
     ,T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode
     ,T_ActionTicketLog.UserID
     ,T_TicketStatus.Name
     ,T_OrderTicket.OrderID
     ,T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode
FROM T_ActionTicketLog 
INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus 
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket 
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint 
    ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
where   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 21780101
```

There are 165 records returned, which is wrong.

The additional left outer join makes the issue.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [T_ActionTicketLog](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [ActionTicketID] [bigint] NULL,
    [TicketOrderID] [bigint] NULL,
    [StatusID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [SalerID] [int] NULL,
    [FiscalID] [int] NULL,
    [BarCode] [bigint] NULL,
    [ReservDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](50) NULL,

CREATE TABLE [T_TicketStatus](
    [ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,


CREATE TABLE [T_TicketPrint](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [CashierID] [int] NULL,
    [BarCode] [bigint] NULL,
    [ControlDigit] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ActionTicketID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [CancelDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TicketBarCode] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OrderTicketID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SetId] [bigint] NULL,

CREATE TABLE [T_OrderTicket](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NULL,
    [ActionTicketID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Status] [smallint] NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
```

How to add the additional field without duplicating records?

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this (grouping, subquery, etc), here is the grouping route:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID
    ,T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode
    ,T_ActionTicketLog.UserID
    ,T_TicketStatus.Name
    ,T_OrderTicket.OrderID
    ,MAX(T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode)
FROM T_ActionTicketLog 
INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket 
    ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint 
    ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
WHERE   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 21780101
GROUP BY T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID
    ,T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode
    ,T_ActionTicketLog.UserID
    ,T_TicketStatus.Name
    ,T_OrderTicket.OrderID
```

You may need to change the MAX() aggregate to something else that makes more sense depending on how multiple TicketPrints associated with an OrderTicket need to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have multipe records in `T_TicketPrint` for each record in `T_OrderTicket` but you only want to display one of these records, in which case I would change the LEFT JOIN to an OUTER APPLY, and just select the top 1 record:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, 
        T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode, 
        T_ActionTicketLog.UserID,
        T_TicketStatus.Name, 
        T_OrderTicket.OrderID, 
        tp.TicketBarCode
FROM    T_ActionTicketLog 
        INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus 
            ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket 
            ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 TicketBarCode
            FROM    T_TicketPrint 
            WHERE   T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
            ORDER BY T_TicketPrint.Created DESC -- NEWEST RECORD
        ) AS tp
WHERE   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 21780101
```

Since you could have multiple records in `T_TicketPrint` the real question then becomes which one should you pick? In the example above I have assumed the latest one, but if this is not correct just change the order by clause in the `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query return 165 record because T_TicketPrint have multiple entry for single ticket.
So, you need a single record for ticket from T_TicketPrint  table.

For that i using group by ActionTicketID  in T_TicketPrint and get barcode.
Your query look like and change as per requirement:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode, T_ActionTicketLog.UserID,
      T_TicketStatus.Name, T_OrderTicket.OrderID, A.TicketBarCode
FROM   T_ActionTicketLog INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select TicketBarCode, ActionTicketID from T_TicketPrint 
group by ActionTicketID,TicketBarCode) as A ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = A.ActionTicketID
where   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 21780101
```

Comment: if barcode is same no need to group by static value column.